# Can't find eSIM option on Google Pixel 3

Tags: settings, google-pixel-3-xl, esim

According to specs, Google Pixel 3 supports eSIM, but under Settings > Mobile networks, there are no relevant options.

Is this depending on whether I'm currently in the service area of a mobile network operator supporting eSIM or should this option appear regardless? If so - why doesn't it appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling developer mode made the option miraculously appear.